# Are these 2 equivalent?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-logic

Is **∀x∀y∀z[φ(x,y)∧p(y,z)->p(x,z)]** equivalent to **∀x∀y∀z[φ(x,y)∧p(x,z)->p(y,z)]** ?

The only thing I can think of is that this question can be answered if we show that `p->q` is equals (↔) το `q->p`, but that's not true because `p->q ↔ ¬p->¬q`, hence `p->q` is not equals to `q->p`. However, I do not know if my logic is correct and if it can be accepted as an answer.

I also think that the (first) **∀x∀y∀z[φ(x,y)∧** part is irrelevant and that i have to focus only to the last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does hold that
$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z \, [p(y,z) \to p(x,z)] \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad
\forall x \forall y \forall z \, [p(x,z) \to p(y,z)],
$$
since $\forall x \forall y$ is the same thing as $\forall y \forall x$. So your logic is incorrect.

Similarly, if $\varphi$ is promised to be symmetric then the equivalence holds, for similar reasons.

A simple example where the equivalence doesn't hold is $\varphi(x,y) = x$, $p(x,y) = x$.

In this case the first statement is
$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z \, [x \land y \to x],
$$
whereas the second statement is
$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z \, [x \land x \to y].
$$
(This assumes that the statements are interpreted as $(\varphi \land p) \to p$ rather than $\varphi \land (p \to p)$.)

Comment: Is there any explanation why ∀x∀y∀z[x∧y→x] is not equivalent to ∀x∀y∀z[x∧x→y]? .... I mean, how would I prove it?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to work it out on your own.

Comment: I see... I tried few things but still not something clear. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the definitions.

Comment: [x∧y→x] => ¬(x∧y)∨x =>¬x∨¬y∨x which is always `true`. But x∧x→y => x->y which can be `false` (if y is false). What about this? :)

Comment: Right, that's the idea.